# Inserting the SAS date value (mmddyy10.) to Oracle table

Tags: oracle, sas, sql-insert, proc-sql

I have a requirement where i need to insert date(mmddyy10.) from a dataset into the oracle table column(Date type). After executing the proc sql insert as shown below date inserted in oracle table are showing as '01/Jan/1960'
Sample :
oracle table : Test
column : close_date
date type : date

SAS data set: Test1
column : close_date
data type: mmddyy10.

```
    proc sql;
    insert into test (close_date) select close_date from test1;
    quit;
```

Please let me know how to handle this issue

Comment: Oracle normally does not use DATE values, only DATETIME values.  Since there are so many seconds in a day any normal date value will look like some time early on the 01JAN1960 if interpreted as a datetime value. Try converting your CLOSE_DATE SAS variable's value to a DATETIME value.  You can use the DHMS() function and just set the hour, minute and second arguments to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try inserting datetime corresponding to your date

```
... DHMS(closedate,0,0,0) ...
```

Although 01-jan-1960 is also the date of SAS date epoch (i.e. a SAS date is a number.  Then number of days since 01-jan-1960).  So, you might have a 0 in your data set.